# How does CrossBrowserTesting.com work?

Tags: cross-browser, vnc, web-testing

I have been curious about better ways to cross browser test than those screenshot services or maintaining my own array of VMs to VNC into. Then today I found crossbrowsertesting.com (which seems to allow you to connect from your browser via VNC to one of their machines running virtually any browser). This is really similar to a solution I had been thinking about, but veered away for a few reasons. I have two questions about this service:

1. if you have used the service, what are its pros/cons?
2. how do they get around people doing all kinds of nasty things on their VMs, since they give you a full desktop to play around in.

Bonus: how do they get around the legal issues regarding people VNC'ing into Windows and using IE when the connecting clients clearly do not own the software?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have not used it sorry, but the standard con for a remote service is that your test site has to be accesible to the web.
2. You secure the desktops with the tools you get with Windows Server, the ability to lock down a user has been around for a while, although it still needs work.

Bonus: You can licence Terminal Services for multiple users, we frequently use it on our "management" servers that allow all the technical staff to log onto one server in the environment and then connect from there to the production servers. We licence it for everyone to log into at once.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from not being able to access local, i.e. on company's intranet or your hard drive, web sites crossbrowsertesting.com may also have a response time issues. VNC is not a very efficient protocol and working using VNC can be a pain.

I prefer tool that allow me to install all relevant browsers on my PC, such as [BrowserSeal](http://browserseal.com)